# Convertir texto a fecha SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, texto

Por favor me Pueden ayudar a convertir este texto a fecha en SQL server

Para este caso necesito Volver la columna de Dato Inicial como esta la de Dato Esperado en la imagen.

Ejemplo
Información inicial
2022-10 (Texto) varchar

Resultado esperado en Fecha tipo 120
(2022-10-31 16:50:00)

Si se puede con Eomonth se lo agradeceria ya que necesito siempre apuntar al último día del mes, ya lo he intentado y siempre me saca error

Ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo el siguiente caso, la columna de Dato Inicial esta como YYYY-MM pero formato texto (Varchar). Esa columna necesito convertirla en la de Dato Esperado como Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Lo he intentado con Convert o Cast y me saca error en formato.

Comment: ¿Cómo se obtienen las horas de las tuplas?. Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xzBhHbp0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿De donde salen las diferentes horas?, y ¿porque ese formato de hora que visualizas?

```
Create table fechas
                     (
                     datoInicial varchar(7)
                     );

Insert into fechas(datoInicial)
values
       ( '2022-01' ),
       ( '2022-02' ),
       ( '2022-03' ),
       ( null ),
       ( '2022-04' ),
       ( '2022-05' );
```

Cuando haces algo de este calado, siempre hay que ir pasito a pasito, hasta que le cojas el tranquillo.

Viendo lo que tienes, y que no se parece a una fecha, lo primero sería ponerle un día, que sepamos que no falla, ya que todos los meses tienen día 1 pero no tienen 31.

```
Select *, 
    t.datoinicial + '-01'  as fechaConDia
from fechas t;
```

[image: Resultado1]

Esto no es ni mucho menos, lo que necesitamos, pero ya tenemos algo que se puede parecer a una fecha. Por tanto probamos a convertir.

```
Select *,
       try_convert(datetime,
                   (t.datoinicial + '-01')
       ) as fechaConvertida
from fechas t;
```

[image: Resultado]

Ahora que ya es un datetime, podemos buscar el último día del mes.

```
Select *,
EoMonth(
try_convert(datetime,
(t.datoinicial + '-01')
)
) as UltimoDiaMes 
from fechas t;
```

[image: Res3]

Claro que eoMonth devuelve un date y no un datetime. Por tanto en vez de convertir a datetime, usemos su tipo.

Select *,
EoMonth(
try_convert(date,
(t.datoinicial + '-01')
)
) as UltimoDiaMes
from fechas t;

Ahora convertimos de nuevo a datetime.

```
Select *,
        Try_convert(datetime,
            EoMonth(
                try_convert(date,
                    (t.datoinicial + '-01')
                )
            )
        ) as UltimoDiaMesDateTime 
from fechas t;
```

[image: Res4]

Pero las horas, no son ni las 10 ni las 12, porque no has mostrado el hecho de porque tengan que ser esas y no otras. Además datetime, tiene también milisegundos, y la fecha que muestras es un formato de salida, no un formato de dato.

Si lo que tienes es un formato, puedes aplicarlo así:

```
Select *,
        Convert(VarChar,
            Try_convert(datetime,
                EoMonth(
                    try_convert(date,
                        (t.datoinicial + '-01')
                    )
                )
            )
        , 20) as MiFormato 
from fechas t;
```

[image: Res5]

Comment: Muchas gracias este era el Query que necesitaba y el formato que requiero.